# How long does it take to charge a 1 uF capacitor with full rectified 5000V output from a flyback transformer?

Tags: capacitor, flyback

If the voltage is 5000 V and the maximum available current is 20 milliamperes, and there's a 1uF capapacitor and 100 ohm resistance of the secondary. We can ignore the internal resistance of the capacitor. If the average voltage is 4500 V (high duty cycle squarewave,) how we find the charging time in this scenario?

Can we just assume 20 mA is enough and go by the RC constant, 0.000001 F * 100 ohm = 0.0001 s and thus after 0.0005 s the capacitor is 99,3% charged?

The main reason I'm asking this is the fact that the transformer output current is limited. We can't just assume any current is available on the secondary just because there is plenty of voltage, as you all know, secondary current is inverse to the voltage multiplication.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128827/discussion-on-question-by-niksa-how-long-does-it-take-to-charge-a-1-uf-capacitor).

Comment: I have moved all comments to chat mainly because there was too high an (argument + rudeness) : Technical information ratio. || Just deleting some could lose some information and make nonsense of others. There was some useful input there that waqs not taken notice of. || OF a transformer is operated so Vout/Vin is equal to the turns ratio it is NOT operating in flyback mode and a full wave rectifier MAY be appropriate. || If Vout/Von is greater than the turns ratio then the system IS in flyback mode and a half wave rectifier is adequate.

Comment: I declined all flags as there was no sensible option available and it's not possiblt to add a comment. Sadly.

Comment: Yes Russell full wave rectification is appropriate in that case and i made a clear distinction between transformer mode (pulsed DC or AC input and AC output) and flyback mode (pulsed DC input, pulsed DC output).

Answer (score 2):

So, is 20 mA enough? If you assume R-C charging all the way, is the current at any time greater than 20 mA? If it is, then your assumption is false and you must find a different solution.

---

If the power supply is effectively a current source, apply the formula: \$I=C\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}\$. You know everything except \$\Delta t\$, so solve for that: \$\Delta t = C\frac{\Delta V}{I}\$. This gives an estimate of 250 ms.

---

However, The real situation is much more complicated. The 20 mA load current @ 5000 V tells you that this power supply can provide 100 W. But this tells you nothing about its characteristics at lower output voltages. Simple flyback power supplies tend to operate in a constant-power mode when not voltage regulating (i.e., when overloaded). This means that as the output voltage is pulled down, the available current goes up. The voltage on a capacitor charging from a constant-power source rises on a quadratic curve, proportional to the square root of the elapsed time.

So if 100 W means 20 mA @ 5000 V, it also means 100 mA @ 1000 V and 1 A @ 100 V. But note that at 1 A, all of the available power is being dissipated in the coil's internal resistance. This is the peak current that the supply can deliver to the capacitor, and it decays quadratically from there, down to 20 mA — at which point, the power supply starts regulating and the R-C exponential curve begins.

Putting that information together, I get the following formula for capacitor current as a function of its terminal voltage. It is valid from v = 0 (i = 1) to v = 4998 (i = .02), at which point, the power supply goes into voltage limiting.

$$i(v)= \frac{-v+\sqrt{v^2 + (200\text{ V})^2}}{200 \Omega}$$

To get voltage as a function of time, you'd have to turn this into a differential equation with the correct initial conditions and solve it — an exercise left for the interested reader.

---

Numerical simulation using a 20 µs sample period says that it takes about 125.4 ms to charge the capacitor under constant-power condtions. In the Perl one-liner below, `$p` is the sample period in µs. Values of 10 and 50 give essentially the same answer.

```perl
perl -e '$v=0;$p=20;for (1..19999) {$v+=(-$v+($v**2+200**2)**.5)/200*$p; print $_*$p, " us: $v\n";exit if $v>5000}'
```

Results:

```
...
125280 us: 4997.56420806406
125300 us: 4997.96424291651
125320 us: 4998.36424577596
125340 us: 4998.76421665007
125360 us: 4999.16415554651
125380 us: 4999.56406247296
125400 us: 4999.96393743707
125420 us: 5000.36378044651
```

Comment: Current cannot be greater than 20mA at any time, most flybacks are near or under 100W, secondary current is in few dozen milliamp range. If resistance of the secondary is ~100Ohm RC constant is 0.000001F * 100Ohm =0.0001s but this assumes current of 50A is available! If we take into account only 20mA is available then roughly around 1 second should take for it to fully charge. I was hoping for an answer along these lines.

Comment: Ok, so t = 0.000001F * 5000V/0.02A = 0.25s. As for the bonus question, why would there be any constant current if cap charging I curve is just that, a curve.

Comment: @Nikša Energy in each energy-transfer is either current limited or energy limited. A point is reached where the cap voltage is high enough that the energy per transfer becomes the limiting factor.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Of course, but that does not mean that current is constant at any point.

Comment: The formula you just applied is based on the assumption that the current is constant at 20 mA for the entire charging period. But at some point, the difference between the source voltage and the capacitor voltage becomes small enough that it can no longer drive 20 mA through the 100-ohm resistance of the coil. From that point on, the current decays exponentially, governed by the R-C time constant. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: As voltage on the cap approaches that of the supply, current tapers off exponentially, of course, that is what i said. "The 20 mA load current @ 5000 V tells you that this power supply can provide 100 W" - that is also exactly what i said. "But simple flyback power supplies tend to operate in a constant-power mode" No, i don't know about you, but neither me nor most people use constant power PSs. Available current is limited and thus the rest of your comments is not relevant.

Comment: @Nikša: I no longer care whether you think my comments are relevant. I'm pursuing this because I find it interesting.

Comment: @DaveTweed Feel free to pursue, but constant-power power supplies are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I see, thank you.